# "can we schedule the call to" vs "can we do the call at"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, verbs, formality

I am writing a business email and want to schedule a call with the recipient.

Which of the following is correct, if any:

1. Can we schedule the call to 9 AM?
2. Can we do the call at 9 AM?
3. Can we have the call at 9 AM?

Answer (score 3):

All three of the options you list are quite acceptable.

Only adjustment I would probably make is to #1, which I'd phrase as "Can we schedule the call *for* 9 AM?" instead. ("schedule... to" isn't particularly common English, it would be "schedule... at" or "schedule... for".)

#2 is a bit more colloquial than the other two; depending on the context that may either be a point to recommend for or against it. (I know you said "business", but that could mean anything from a colleague you work with often to a new client you've never met. #2 would be more suited to the former than the latter, generally.)

Comment: I'm not a fan of #3. It may not be grammatically incorrect, but I think the expression "have the call" is not quite idiomatic.

Comment: @J.R. Huh, really? Compare "have the meeting", which is _extremely_ common English phrasing. I don't think I really "hear" anything particularly wrong with "have the call", myself.

Comment: [*shrugs*] "Have the meeting" is fine, of course. For some reason, "have the call" seems a little off to me; I'd be inclined to use a different verb, I think: _make the call, do the call_ – or even use _call_ as the verb: _Why don't you call me at 9?_ (I just like Nos. 1 and 2 a little more than 3, that's all.)

Comment: I disagree. I've never heard anyone use 'to' when scheduling something as in #1. It sounds flat wrong to me. 'Do the call' is slang, as far as I'm concerned, albeit very common. Using 'do' when there's another more precise verb just seems lazy. I would use 'schedule the call' as suggested in the question's title, especially for a business letter. I also don't see anything wrong with 'have the call'. I would recommend 'Schedule the call at' over all the others.

Comment: @dwilli I'm still not clear who/what you "disagree" with, though. If I'm reading your comment correctly it sounds like it's in complete agreement with my answer, no? (Or is it just that I opened with "All three of the options you list are quite acceptable." before immediately walking that back and pointing out most of the same issues you have?)

Comment: @FeRD yes, you're right, it's probably mostly your first statement that caught my attention. Plus the fact that I've never heard a native speaker say 'schedule to'. Anyway, thanks for asking. I'd rather discuss it than start downvoting somebody else.